# Can't receive response from nodejs backend in postman

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have following issue in my simple nodejs backend - postman does sending post request and can't get message from the code:

```
import express from 'express';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { dirname } from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import cors from "cors";
var app = express();
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));




app.post("/register",function(req,res){

      fs.readFileSync( __dirname + "/" + "users.json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
      var users=JSON.parse(data);
      users["users"].push(req.body);
      var check=false;
      fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + "/" + "users.json", JSON.stringify(users),'utf8', function (err) {
         if(err){
            res.send(JSON.stringify("error"));
            check=true;
         }
         if(!check){
            res.send(JSON.stringify("Created")); 
         }
      })

           
   })
})
var server = app.listen(8081,function() {
   console.log("server start running");
})
```

I am sending to : http://localhost:8081/register message : {"name":"add","password":"add"}

Comment: just to be sure, you read the `users.json` **and** write on it in a single closure?

Comment: I am overwritting all users.json file in every register invocation. Do not know if there is critical section issue I am starting to learn node. but I want to make single request and get response

Comment: also, just to be sure, i want to know your nodejs version. i can't find `readFileSync` with callback in [the docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/fs.html#fsreadfilesyncpath-options).

Comment: node version: v16.16.0

Comment: the issue has been solved thanks :)

Comment: nice, you can answer your own question. it might help someone else in the future.